# ListView not refreshing after raising PropertyChangedEvent on ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, binding

I am trying to create a File Explorer style TreeView/ListView window that will allow the user to select a "Project" from within a "ProjectFolder".

The "ProjectFolder" tree is bound to a property on my ViewModel called "RootProjectFolders" and the "Project" list is bound to a property called "ProjectsInSelectedFolder".  Things were mostly working; however, I was getting null exceptions when I first loaded the window because the "SelectedFolder" had not yet been set.  When I tried to implement a simple check to make sure that the "SelectedFolder" was not null, my "Project" ListView stopped refreshing.

```
if ((this.SelectedFolder != null) && (this.SelectedFolder.ProjectFolder.Projects != null))
{
   foreach (Project project in this.SelectedFolder.ProjectFolder.Projects)
   {
      _projectsInSelectedFolder.Add(new ProjectViewModel(project));
   }
}
base.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("ProjectsInSelectedFolder");
```

If I remove `(this.SelectedFolder != null)` from the above, the ListView will update, but I will get an NullException error.  Why is that check breaking my binding?

Following up on the request for additional information, here is the XAML of the TreeView and ListView that are binding to the properties on the ViewModel:

```
<TreeView Name="treeviewProjectFolders" Grid.Column="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RootProjectFolders}">
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
        <GridSplitter Name="splitterProjects" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <ListView Name="listviewProjects" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProjectsInSelectedFolder}">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

And here is the ViewModel

```
public class SelectProjectViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Fields
    List<ProjectViewModel> _projectsInSelectedFolder;
    List<ProjectFolderViewModel> _rootProjectFolders;
    static ProjectFolderViewModel _selectedFolder = null;
    ProjectViewModel _selectedProject;
    #endregion // Fields

    #region Constructor
    public SelectProjectViewModel(ProjectFolders rootProjectFolders)
    {
        if (_rootProjectFolders != null) { _rootProjectFolders.Clear(); }            
        _rootProjectFolders = new List<ProjectFolderViewModel>();
        foreach (ProjectFolder rootFolder in rootProjectFolders)
        {
            _rootProjectFolders.Add(new ProjectFolderViewModel(rootFolder, this));
        }
        _projectsInSelectedFolder = new List<ProjectViewModel>();
        // Subscribe to events
        this.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
    }
    #endregion // Constructor

    #region Properties
    public List<ProjectFolderViewModel> RootProjectFolders
    {
        get
        {
            return _rootProjectFolders;
        }
    }        
    public List<ProjectViewModel> ProjectsInSelectedFolder
    {
        get
        {                
            return _projectsInSelectedFolder;
        }
    }
    public ProjectFolderViewModel SelectedFolder
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _selectedFolder; 
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedFolder != value)
            {
                _selectedFolder = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public ProjectViewModel SelectedProject
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedProject;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedProject = value;
            base.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SelectedProject");
        }
    }
    #endregion // Properties

    #region Methods
    public void FindSelectedFolder(ProjectFolderViewModel root)
    {
        if (root.IsSelected) { _selectedFolder = root; }
        else
        {
            foreach (ProjectFolderViewModel folder in root.Children)
            {
                if (_selectedFolder == null)
                {
                    FindSelectedFolder(folder);
                }
            }
        }            
    }
    #endregion // Methods

    #region Event Handlers
    void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case "SelectedFolder":
                _selectedFolder = null;
                foreach (ProjectFolderViewModel root in this.RootProjectFolders)
                {
                    if (_selectedFolder == null)
                    {
                        this.FindSelectedFolder(root);
                    }
                }
                _projectsInSelectedFolder.Clear();
                if ((this.SelectedFolder != null) && (this.SelectedFolder.ProjectFolder.Projects != null))
                {
                    foreach (Project project in this.SelectedFolder.ProjectFolder.Projects)
                    {
                        _projectsInSelectedFolder.Add(new ProjectViewModel(project));
                    }
                }
                base.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("ProjectsInSelectedFolder");
                break;
        }
    }
    #endregion // Event Handlers
```

Also, here is the ViewModel for the individual project folders that are used to raise the "SelectedFolder" property:

```
public class ProjectFolderViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Fields
    ReadOnlyCollection<ProjectFolderViewModel> _children;
    List<ProjectFolderViewModel> _childrenList;
    bool _isExpanded;
    bool _isSelected;
    ProjectFolderViewModel _parentNode;
    SelectProjectViewModel _parentTree;
    ProjectFolder _projectFolder;        
    #endregion // Fields

    #region Constructor
    public ProjectFolderViewModel(ProjectFolder projectFolder, SelectProjectViewModel parentTree) : this(projectFolder, parentTree, null)
    { }
    private ProjectFolderViewModel(ProjectFolder projectFolder, SelectProjectViewModel parentTree, ProjectFolderViewModel parentNode)
    {
        _projectFolder = projectFolder;
        _parentTree = parentTree;
        _parentNode = parentNode;
        _childrenList = new List<ProjectFolderViewModel>();
        foreach (ProjectFolder child in _projectFolder.ChildFolders)
        {
            _childrenList.Add(new ProjectFolderViewModel(child, _parentTree));
        }
        _children = new ReadOnlyCollection<ProjectFolderViewModel>(_childrenList);
    }
    #endregion // Constructor

    #region Properties
    public ReadOnlyCollection<ProjectFolderViewModel> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return _children;
        }
    }
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _isExpanded; 
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _isExpanded)
            {
                _isExpanded = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("IsExpanded");
            }
            // Expand all the way up to the root.
            if (_isExpanded && _parentNode != null)
                _parentNode.IsExpanded = true;
        }
    }
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return _isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            base.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("IsSelected");
            //if (_isSelected)
            //{ 
                _parentTree.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SelectedFolder");
            //}
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _projectFolder.Name;
        }
    }
    public ProjectFolder ProjectFolder
    {
        get
        {
            return _projectFolder;
        }
    }
    #endregion // Properties
```

Comment: How removing null check will update listView when it gets crashed at first place?

Comment: Could you show the code that implements both properties? i.e. the getters and setters of both properties? Also, where the "RootProjectFolders" is initialized?

Comment: You have omitted lots of code that we need to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change all your

```
List<T> to observablecollection<T>
```

because when ever there is new file or folder your adding the Item, your not creating new List, since observablecollection implements INotifyCollectionChanged, and INotifyPropertyChanged it'll internally take care of notifying and refreshing the View. But list cant do that

Comment: Thank you.  This worked; however, I'm still confused as to why the List<T> approach wasn't working since I was directly raising the property changed event to alert the ListView that its ItemsSource had changed. Does that not cause the ListView to refresh, and why was it "working" (ignoring the NullException) until I added the "null" check? Very strange.